# How to change Identity value in Web Api 2

Tags: c#, .net, oauth

I'm developing a web api using OAuth token based for authentication.

When the token is generated i register at the identity.

```
var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Options.AuthenticationType);
                identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, context.UserName));
 identity.AddClaim(new Claim("CustomerId", usuario.IdCustomer.ToString()));
  var principal = new GenericPrincipal(identity, new string[] { role.Profile.ToString() });

                Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;

                context.Validated(identity);
```

In an especified moment, i need to change an identity claim value.
I can access than and manipulate, but the changes dont take effects.

```
[Authorize]
    [HttpPatch]
    [Route("current/customer/{id}")]
    public async Task ChangeSessionCustomer(int id)
    {
        var context = HttpContext.Current;
        IAuthenticationManager AuthenticationManager = context.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
        var identity = (ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity;

        var claimCustomerId = identity.FindFirst("CustomerId");
        identity.RemoveClaim(claimCustomerId);
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim("CustomerId", id.ToString()));

    }
```

its possible change the identity value in Thered.Principal ?

Answer (score 1):

I would think to cut down on complexity of having a "ChangeSessionCustomer", I would just reauthorize the user and assign a new token.

Comment: that was exactly what i'd. Tnkz.